# Where is MVC3's App_Code folder

Tags: helper, asp.net-mvc-3

[This post contains a nicely succinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981175/where-should-i-place-declarative-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-3) explanation for implementing razor helpers. But it refers to the use of the 'App_Code' folder - something i can't get my MVC3-transitioned-from-MVC2 project to create. I understand this has to do with WebSite vs. Web App but to be honest - i can't remember if the original creation was site or app. Since there's menu selection 'Convert to Web Application' seems it was created as a Web Site. But then there should be a App_Code dir, yes?

Attempting to recreate the steps from the original post (within a manually created 'App_Code' folder) presents pre-compile errors (MyHelpers does not exist in this context) - but the strategy _does work. - at least the simple hello stuff did. so i shouldn't argue with success? MVC3/Razor isn't fully intellisensed yet?

thx

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is not Website by default, so you don't need to have App_BlahBlah folders!

Answer (score 0):

I created an app_code directory by just creating a folder called app_code.  MVC3 dealt with this file correctly by creating static methods for the code I put in there.  When I reopened my solution later, the app_code file had disappeared.  I eventually found that the app_code file was marked as a hidden folder by visual studio. 
In this virtual machine I have the RTM VS 2010.  not sure if this was fixed in SP1.